# Window functions in order by clause (SQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table `transactions` like this:

```
| id |    date    | amount |
+----+------------+--------+
|  1 | 2023-01-01 |    3   |
|  2 | 2023-02-01 |    5   |
|  3 | 2023-03-01 |    4   |
|  4 | 2023-04-01 |    2   |
|  5 | 2023-05-01 |    7   |
|  6 | 2023-06-01 |    4   |
+----+------------+--------+
```

I don't understand the behavior of this SQL query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM transactions ORDER BY SUM(amount) OVER (ORDER BY id) < 15;
```

Result:

```
+----+------------+--------+
| id |    date    | amount |
+----+------------+--------+
|  5 | 2023-05-01 |    7   |
|  6 | 2023-06-01 |    4   |
|  1 | 2023-01-01 |    3   |
|  2 | 2023-02-01 |    5   |
|  3 | 2023-03-01 |    4   |
|  4 | 2023-04-01 |    2   |
+----+------------+--------+
```

Could someone explain how a window function generally works with the ORDER BY clause?
Why is this the result I'm getting?
Thanks !

Comment: False come before True. 3+5+4+2 < 15. To understand better, try using the same window function as a column added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple things going on here:

1. You haven't `partitioned by` anything; therefore every row is treated as a single partition.
2. You are basically sorting on Boolean and SUM.

Given this data...

```
create table transactions (
  id integer, 
  date date, 
  amount integer
  );
  
insert into transactions values 
(1, '2023-01-01', 3),
(2, '2023-02-01', 5),
(3, '2023-03-01', 4),
(4, '2023-04-01', 2),
(5, '2023-05-01', 7),
(6, '2023-06-01', 4);
```

---

```
SELECT *,  
 SUM(amount) OVER (ORDER BY id) as abc, 
 sum(amount) over (ORDER BY ID) < 15 as abc2
FROM transactions 
ORDER BY SUM(amount) OVER (ORDER BY id) < 15;
```

| id | date | amount | abc | abc2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 2023-05-01T00:00:00.000Z | 7 | 21 | false |
| 6 | 2023-06-01T00:00:00.000Z | 4 | 25 | false |
| 1 | 2023-01-01T00:00:00.000Z | 3 | 3 | true |
| 2 | 2023-02-01T00:00:00.000Z | 5 | 8 | true |
| 3 | 2023-03-01T00:00:00.000Z | 4 | 12 | true |
| 4 | 2023-04-01T00:00:00.000Z | 2 | 14 | true |

---

You'll notice that you're sorting on Boolean first, and then SUM second.

So for example id 3 is preceded by ids 1 and 2 when ordering by id. Their combined (cumulative) sum AMOUNT is 12. That is less than 15, so it's TRUE.

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/28RPrZMiqUA4tPP5puwEcc/0)

Comment: ```and then SUM second.```. Its not sorting by SUM second, that is an implementation detail. because the window function orders by `id`, it just happens that the rows end up in that order, and the expanding sum just happens to be collinear with `id` in this toy example. In general you should not rely on the order of the rows if you don't explicitly specify it.